# Continuous task waiting and suspend it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In a spring boot web application, I need to be able to do two tasks.

Tasks

1. Always check on the serial port if there is some data to read. Somebody can have passed a card on the scan. I think this task needs to start with the application.
2. If a new member comes, I need to scan a card, task 1 needs to be suspended/stopped... if the card is not assigned to anybody, it's assigned to this member. Restart task 1.

I don't know what is the best way to do task 1 to facilitate task 2.

I see there are many possibility: `@Scheduled`, `TaskScheduler` who will execute a thread...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You should make one Thread that reads data from the serial port in a loop and dispatches this data as events when something usefull was readed to a proper service that will serve this.

Comment: ok but that don't really answer question... It's sure the task will call a service to do that...

important thinkg is how to call task 1 and how task 2 will put in pause task 2

Comment: If the thread will directly invoke some service method it will not back to read anything untli the service method will return, is this ok?

Comment: ok, I will give more informaiton.
task 1, read serial port, if a card is scanned, value is sent to a service layer who check in the database if the id is assigned...
task 2, if a new user come, a card is gived to the user, card id is unknown so the user must scan it before to get it assigned to him. When user pass it's card, I don't want task 1 to be runned... it's two different scenario.

Comment: Why do you want to stop the reading from serial port when someone scan a card?

Comment: Because it's two different process. Both will not happen at the same time.
Task two is "on demand", will execuse only when we click on a button in the ui.